# How to understand the event log to determine why the .net system crashes after sometime?

Tags: c#, sockets, event-handling

I have developed a software using c# which need to run 24X7. Here I am using Socket connection to connect with the server and getting the response as the software is transferring user messages via Socket to Facebook from their hand phone.

Before it was working fine but since few days it is crashing after running for few hours.
So when I checked my event log then I found this below logs which is quite unfamiliar to me:

Error occurred at: 5:05:11 AM

```
  Faulting application name: USSD_FB.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5382ad72
  Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17965, time stamp: 0x506dcae6
  Exception code: 0xe0434352
  Fault offset: 0x000000000000bccd
  Faulting process id: 0x3618
  Faulting application start time: 0x01cf79ea973870e8
  Faulting application path: E:\USSD_FB\USSD_FB\bin\Debug\USSD_FB.exe
  Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
  Report Id: 96e446f9-e5e2-11e3-8ae7-0015175fd6c0
```

This error occurred at 5:05:10 AM:

```
  Application: USSD_FB.exe
  Framework Version: v4.0.30319
  Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
  Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  Stack:
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(System.IAsyncResult)
  at USSD_FB.frmBulk.ReceiveCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
  at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
  at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
 at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
 at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
 at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

I would really appreciate if someone help me to understand the above event log which may help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SocketException` is not familiar to you?

Comment: I am so sorry I am also not so familiar to socket exception. By the way is it suggesting that Kernellbase is having problem due to this socket exception as well?

Comment: That's actually confusing, forget about it. Problem is in `frmBulk.ReceiveCallback` method, you simply need a try/catch(SocketException) around `socket.EndReceive`.

Answer (score 2):

According to your stack trace, the following happeneds:

1. You call `Socket.BeginReceive` and hand it a `CallBack` to invoke once it finishes receiving your data
2. Your callback is invoked. Inside the callback you call `EndReceive` and pass it your `IAsyncResult` callback
3. `EndReceive` trys to access the stream, but the exception occurs, meaning something happend to the `Socket`. You don't `catch` a `SocketException` inside your callback and it crashes the process.

Fron MSDN, [`Socket.EndReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you receive a SocketException, use the SocketException.ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in the MSDN library for a detailed description of the error

You need to wrap  `yourUSSD_FB.frmBulk.ReceiveCallback(System.IAsyncResult)` method with a `catch (SocketException)` clause and handle the exception.